# react-native expo managed app recording not supported by openai

Tags: react-native, openai-api, expo-av, openai-whisper

I'm getting this error back from openai's transcription endpoint;

```
message: "The audio file could not be decoded or its format is not supported."
```

What I'm doing:

- Setting recording options to mp4;
- Move the new recording into a temporary file Directory;
- Create form data and call openai transcriptions endpoint;

What's happening:

- I'm getting an error back from openai API saying the "The audio file could not be decoded or its format is not supported";
- [openai supported formats](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/7031512-whisper-api-faq#:%7E:text=What%20file%20formats,mpeg)
- [IOS supported audio files](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/CoreAudioEssentials/CoreAudioEssentials.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003577-CH10-SW47:%7E:text=iPhone%20Audio%20File,see%20Codecs.)
- [Expo go recordingOptions config](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/audio/#recordingoptions)

Here is what I'm doing;

```
  async function startRecording() {
    try {
      // needed for IoS
      if (audioPermission) {
        await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
          allowsRecordingIOS: true,
          playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
        });
      }

      const newRecording = new Audio.Recording();

      const recordingOptions = {
        android: {
          extension: '.mp4',
          outputFormat: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_OUTPUT_FORMAT_MPEG_4,
          audioEncoder: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_AUDIO_ENCODER_AAC,
        },
        ios: {
          extension: '.mp4',
          outputFormat: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_IOS_OUTPUT_FORMAT_MPEG4AAC,
          audioQuality: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_IOS_AUDIO_QUALITY_HIGH,
        },
      };

      console.log('Starting Recording')
      await newRecording.prepareToRecordAsync(
        recordingOptions
      );

      await newRecording.startAsync();
      setRecording(newRecording);
      setRecordingStatus('recording');

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to start recording', error);
    }
  }

  async function stopRecording() {
    try {
      if (recordingStatus == 'recording') {
        console.log('Stopping recording..');
        await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
        const recordingUri = recording.getURI();
        console.log('Recording stopped and stored at URI', recordingUri);
        console.log('OPENAI_API_KEY', OPENAI_API_KEY);
        // Create a file name for the new recording
        const fileName = `recording-${Date.now()}.mp4`;

        // Calls openai translations endpoint
        try {
          const url = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions';
          const headers = {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${OPENAI_API_KEY}`,
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          };

          // Copy the recording file to a temporary directory
          const tempDirectory = FileSystem.cacheDirectory + 'recordings/';
          await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(tempDirectory, { intermediates: true });
          const tempRecordingUri = tempDirectory + fileName;
          await FileSystem.copyAsync({
            from: recordingUri,
            to: tempRecordingUri,
          });


          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('file', {
            uri: tempRecordingUri,
            name: fileName,
            type: 'audio/mp4', // Change to the desired audio format
          });
          formData.append('model', 'whisper-1');

          // const formData = new FormData();
          // formData.append('file', fileData, fileName);
          // formData.append('model', 'whisper-1');

          axios.post(url, formData, { headers })
            .then(response => {
              console.log('Transcription response:', response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.error('Error:', error);
            });

        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      }
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to stop recording', error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried mp3 instead? It's more widely used for audio and may be better supported. Those docs are not very helpful.

Comment: Hey Abe, yeah I tried using mp3. I'm gonna have 1 more go with mp3

Comment: If I specify .mp3 file extension in the expo go config it returns an error!  ERROR  Failed to start recording [Error: Prepare encountered an error: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1718449215 "(null)"]

Comment: @Ibra Did you end up fixing this? I am having the same issue on Android. iOS works fine.